# How to automatically run a Node.js program using VSCode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I was wondering whether there is a way to execute a Node.js program using some keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio Code.

For instance, while I am coding in the editor, instead of having to manually open the Integrated Terminal in Visual Studio Code and then type let's say `node app.js`, can I just configure a key to automatically do this?

Below shown is an illustration of what I want:

[image]

I want to run the file `app.js` in the terminal without having to go there again and again and type `node app` (or even by using the up arrow key to bring the last entry from the terminal's history).

Note: I found one way of doing so and that is to go to the **Debug console**. But sometimes, it doesn't display full results. For instance, when logging a module, it displays one line with a caret which can be used to inspect details of the logged object further, but when I press the caret, it says that *there is no debugger to view the object*.

Comment: There's definitely a hotkey to do this, but to achieve what you want, I think Nodemon would work better? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-nodemon

Comment: What's that hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shell [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) or an npm [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) that runs `node app.js`. You can then bind a hotkey for running a task in the VS Code key binding settings.
The npm extension should automatically detect every script in the package.json file and provide them as a task if the `task.autoDetect` setting is set to on. You can simply add a start script that runs `node app.js`. I have then set up a hotkey that reruns the latest task:
`{ "key": "ctrl+r b", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.reRunTask" },`

Comment: The npm handles tasks for node.js automatically. I've added a rough overview as an edit.

Comment: I didn't get the last comment you wrote. Could you please explain it a bit further?